# AWS API Gateway Invoke URL link works in browser but not with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: amazon-web-services, xmlhttprequest, aws-api-gateway

Whenever I use the following to try and load the json:

'''

```
<script>
    function shutDown() {
      let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open("GET", "https://er2uqo9cyc.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/testing/ec2");
      request.send();
      request.onload = () => {
          console.log(request);
          if (request.status == 200) {
              console.log(JSON.parse(request.response));
          } else {
              console.log('error ${request.status} ${request.statusText}');
          }
      }
    }
</script>
```

'''

I get the following error in the console of my browser, and no JSON:
'''

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (styles.css, line 0)
[Error] Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 200
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://er2uqo9cyc.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/testing/ec2 due to access control checks.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 200 (ec2, line 0)
```

'''

Why isn't it working with XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: Where does `http://localhost:8080` come from?

Comment: Im calling the API from a program on my own machine